# Encrypting Authentication Cookies using Data Protection Keys Stored in Database for .Net Core and .Net Framework 4.x Websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, data-protection, cookie-authentication

**Question**:
How can I encrypt authentication cookies using data protection keys stored in a database rather than the file system or file share for Asp.Net Framework 4.x and Asp.Net Core 2 websites?

**Context**:
I have a .Net Framework 4.x website and a .Net Core 2.0 website.  I need to share authentication cookies between these two apps and encrypt the data using DataProtection keys.
In production, these applications are hosted on several web servers.  So, I also need to share the keys between servers, hence the database.
Currently, the data protections keys are manually sync'd across file system locations on each server. 
I would like to have a common location for the data protection keys that each web server can use.
The obvious solution is a file share but this introduces a single-point of failure to the architecture.
I would rather use the common database backing these two apps. 
I know the database itself is a SPoF, but it already is and always will be.
Using it for this purpose does not increase risk.

I know that I can create my own IXmlRepository implementation that gets and saves data protection keys to my database.
I have done this and it works well. During debug, I can see the application getting and setting data protection keys in my database.

I use this in StartUp.cs where DataProtectionRepository is my implementation to a database:

```
services.AddSingleton<IXmlRepository, DataProtectionRepository>();
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
services.AddDataProtection().AddKeyManagementOptions(opt =>
            opt.XmlRepository =
                new DataProtectionRepository(serviceProvider.GetService<DataProtectionContext>()));
```

The problem is when I set up CookieAuthenticationOptions, the TicketDataFormat property requires an implementation of IDataProtector to construct.  IDataProtector is provided by DataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector, but to create a data protection provider a DirectoryInfo object indicating the location where the keys are to be stored is required.

```
var securityOptions = 
services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOptions<SecurityOptions>>();
var protectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(securityOptions.Value.KeyringLocation));
var dataProtector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector("CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Federation", "v2");
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                           {
                               <blah>
                               options.TicketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
                               <blah>
                           });
```

I suppose I could create my own implementation of IDataProtectionProvider and IDataProtector, but this seems hairy and perilous since the IDataProtector handles the actual protection and un-protection of data payloads but does not expose any detail of how keys are retrieved or from where they are sourced.  Also, I don't really want to change any of the actual protect/unprotect functionality.  I merely want to retrieve the keys from my repository.

I have trouble believing I'm unique with this problem.  Am I completely down the wrong path?  Is there an alternate solution or should I just put in a file share and move on?

Thanks.

Comment: So the file system was the only common thing between Core and older versions which didn't need dependencies on other pieces or a DI system, hence it being the only thing we supported. So yea, you're in an unsupported scenario right now I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks, @blowdart.  I'll implement the share and move on.

Comment: Are you able to finish it? Could you please check the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845512/how-to-share-encrypted-cookies-between-asp-net-and-asp-net-core